# all possible sub-digit of a given number

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on program to get all possible (overlapping and non-overlapping)sub-digit of given number. for example n=789. All the possible sub-digits are 789,7,8,9,78,79,89. But by my code i am getting only overlapping sub-digits only. Can you please help me how to get all non-overlapping subdigits also

```
  n = 789
  N = str(n)
  r = len(N)
  for i in range(0, r+1):
     for j in range(i, r+1):
         print(N[i:j])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools`

```
import itertools
def findsubsets(s):
    return [''.join([str(k) for k in i]) for j in range(len(s)) for i in itertools.combinations(s, j) if i!=()]
# Driver Code
s=789
s={int(i) for i in str(s)}
print(findsubsets(s))
```

More better solution is:

```
from itertools import combinations
x = 789
y=[int(''.join(l)) for i in range(len(str(x))) for l in combinations(str(x), i+1)]
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  `N[i:j]` to  `N[i:j+1]` and `range(0, r+1)` to `range(0, r)`

```py
n = 789
N = str(n)
r = len(N)

for i in range(0, r):
    for j in range(i, r):
        print( N[i:j+1])
```

```
7
78
789
8
89
9
```